# how do i open the index.html file instead of the file directory in a folder?

Tags: html, .htaccess

how do I get the index.html file to open when you go to file:///C:/Users/ONT%20Studios/Downloads/test/ i.e. can I make it so it doesn't show the directories but opens the index.html file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged this [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess), which is a configuration file format for Apache HTTPD, but you aren't using Apache HTTPD or any other HTTP server.

You are just reading a local directory with your web browser.

Web browsers do not have features to load an index.html instead of showing a directory listing when you point them at a directory.

Use an HTTP server.